# Get the last word of string

Tags: java, string

How can I get the last word of an string if my string is like that "hello is my new car "(after the word car there is an white space).

I want to know how remove it too.

Thank you so much

Comment: Elbow grease, that's how.

Comment: use `trim()` to remove leading blanks and substring and indexOf blank to find the last word

Comment: Regular expressions, that's how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case, you can first trim the string:

```
String s = "hello is my new car ".trim();
```

Trim removes all trailing and leading spaces.

Then you can split the String like:

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
```

Once you have that you can simply get the last index which will be the last word:

```
String lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
```

Ofcourse, for more complex issues regex would be a better option.

**UPDATE:**

In order to remove this word from the string you can simply replace it:

```
String withoutWord = s.replace(lastWord, "");
```

Comment: thanks!!! works fine! And to remove and get "hello is my new"? thanks a lot

Comment: @user3714696 [link]https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html use remove method

Comment: @user3714696 I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
String w =  "hello is my new car ".trim();
String lastWord = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split by whitespace and take the last element.

```
String[] s = "hello is my new car".split(" ");

String lastWord = s[lenght-1];
```

Comment: Well, `s.last`...